# Where I can get detail information to build Restful API?

Tags: intellij-idea, angular-dart, dart-webui

I developed Flutter mobile app. I need to develop a restful api for my flutter mobile app. I am using macOS and IntelliJ.

I install dart plugin. I try to create a first angular dart project and I found that there is a lib directory which has an error.

lib/generated/i18n.dart and import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart'; also 
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; couldn't found.

What is the steps to create a Angular Dart WebApp project using IntelliJ? I try to install web storm but couldn't find any community edition.

Any help please?

Comment: You write "I try to create a first angular dart project" and then post a Flutter-related error message. You also write about Flutter and Angular but Restful APIs usually live on the server, not on the client. Flutter and Angular are client-only. To me it's not clear what the question is about.

Comment: I thought I can create a web api using angular dart. I open my InteliiJ and choose Dart->Angular Web project. When opens I get lib folder and the files with error that I describe. I guess I shouldn't use IntelliJ. https://news.dartlang.org/2015/03/create-your-own-rest-api-with-dart.html

Comment: Angular is a client framework for building browser user interfaces - similar to what Flutter does for mobile.

Comment: Thanks Günter, I was expecting to find solution with Dart Angular Web, I didn't know that I have to use another framework like aqueduct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an API you need to use a back-end framework, and you would probably want to choose one depending on the languages you know.
If you want to use Dart for the API too, you can't use Angular Dart since that's a front-end framework and you can't use that to build a web API.
Simply Googling, you will find  [Aqueduct](https://aqueduct.io/).
About that error: are you trying to import Flutter libraries in a Dart project?

Comment: For my Flutter app I thought I can develope restful api using Dart web. https://news.dartlang.org/2015/03/create-your-own-rest-api-with-dart.html

Comment: I will try the Aqueduct

Comment: your info made my day just great.  Thank you. Introduction video, how to create your rest api in dart and how to setup aqueduct https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rf6uAcAglzc